# Is this the real face of Tali?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Reading the [article of Tali](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tali#Mass_Effect_3) in the wiki I found a picture of her without the mask.
Is it real or a good fake?

It appears that you need to have a romance with her to get the picture.

[image: Tali's face]

Comment: It's always the same thing. Ooh, she could get sick. Ooh, she's vulnerable. I wonder what she looks like under the helmet.

Comment: Maybe this image (as debatable as the source may be) should be considered a spoiler?

Comment: It is a bad fake. Unfortunately, it is in the game.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That picture of her **is** the actual picture used in-game. It's a gift to you from her after the Rannoch missions (assuming you're romancing her), and can be found next to your bed after speaking with her.

The image itself is a photoshopped copy of a photograph taken from a website that specializes in stock photos. (Stock Photo on Left)

[image]

Personally, I'm going to keep pretending that [this fan art is the real Tali.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNzYm.jpg)

Comment: added another picture for comparison.

Comment: Thanks, @RavenDreamer. I can't add pictures from my phone, or I would've put that one in from the beginning.

Comment: /tipmonocle. I do what I can.

Comment: That fan art is horrible, sorry.  (The stock image edit is also horrible, but still)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explorative research... Finally, Tali exposed for the beauty she is.

Comment: well... we can see the full extent of her horrible immune system now

Comment: Fan Art no longer present :(

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh Fixed!